# Knowing your workload type using dmv's?

Tags: sql-server, dmv

Is there a DMV through which I can tell that my workload type is 'ad hoc'?

Answer (score 5):

This is the one I would use, courtesy of [Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/plan-cache-and-optimizing-for-adhoc-workloads/):

```
SELECT objtype AS [CacheType]
, count_big(*) AS [Total Plans]
, sum(cast(size_in_bytes as decimal(18,2)))/1024/1024 AS [Total MBs]
, avg(usecounts) AS [Avg Use Count]
, sum(cast((CASE WHEN usecounts = 1 THEN size_in_bytes ELSE 0 END) as decimal(18,2)))/1024/1024 AS [Total MBs - USE Count 1]
, sum(CASE WHEN usecounts = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Plans - USE Count 1]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
GROUP BY objtype
ORDER BY [Total MBs - USE Count 1] DESC
```

It splits out the plan size and total number of plans by Type e.g. Adhoc, Prepared, Procedure, Trigger, View etc.

**EDIT:**

If you want to then find out the actual pressure each type is placing on the server, you can join the `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` to `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` through the `plan_handle` and order by `total_worker_time` (for CPU) or `total_elapsed_time` (for Duration).

Answer (score 1):

The DMF `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` returns null in the columns dbid, objectid and number for adhoc and prepared statements.

If your procedure cache is reflective of the typical workload then querying `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` or `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` and cross applying to `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` will give you an idea.